# Filter to API integration

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm doing an API integration between an ERP and a CRM using Python and requests library. The goal is get products in ERP and send to CRM. My code is working, but it's sending dupes of products already existent in CRM. Someone have a tip to fix this? Thanks in advance.

I've already tried to pick SKU product from ERP and compare with existences SKUs in CRM, and compare the name of products as well, but it's not filtering.

```
ploomes_url = 'https://public5-api2.ploomes.com/Products'

for product in produtos_bling:
    cod_produto_bling = product['codigo']  # Substitua 'descricao' pelo campo correto do Bling que contém o nome do produto

# Passo 3.1: Consulta à API do Ploomes para verificar se o produto já existe pelo nome
search_url = f'https://public5-api2.ploomes.com/Products?$filter=Code eq \'{cod_produto_bling}\''
response_search = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers_ploomes)

if response_search.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Produto '{cod_produto_bling}' já existe no Ploomes. Não será enviado novamente.")
    continue
else:
    print("Erro ao consultar produto no Ploomes:", response_search.status_code)
    continue
```

Comment: Is this the code that checks if the SKU from the ERP exists in the CRM? What happens when you run it? What do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your code to fix the indentation

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, this is the code. The expectation is: return me a message saying if the SKU already exists on CRM and don't bring me the same product again. But when I run it, I got the message even if the product isn't on CRM (it's a test profile of mine, so I know everything that's on there) and the code still pick the product again. In the end, neither the recognize process of check the code or select the right products isn't work properly.

Comment: I recommend removing the loop for now and trying this with a specific code that you know already exists in the CRM. Get this much working first before going any further. When you have code to do that small part, you can add more `print()` statements to examine the response to figure out what is going on.

Comment: You can also use a HTTP client such as curl or postman to check the request to the CRM to make sure you are doing it right.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with Insomnia opened here, but still struggling

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code prints if the product exists without executing the next code.  This causes duplicates. you should change the code to only send the product if it doesn't exist

Comment: It is the same thing it looks to me. Do you have some suggestions about how can I do that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).